# How to add onclick to a link with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using following segment of code to add `onclick` to anchor tag but apparently it is not working.

```
var address_edit = $('.edit-user a').attr('href'));
$('.edit-user a').prop('onclick', 'Popup("address_edit","Edit","900","500");')
```

**What I want:**

This is my code on inspect element:

```
<div class="edit-user">
    <a href="example.com/nokidding">No kidding</a>
</div>
```

This is what I need it to be:

```
<div class="edit-user">
    <a onclick='Popup("address_edit","Edit","900","500");' href="example.com/nokidding">No kidding</a>
</div>
```

Comment: When there is " href " in anchor it ll be redirected to another page. So its of no use writing " onclick ".

Comment: Just remove the href attribute in your anchor tag.

Comment: I kept href as fallback

Comment: You need show popup or to redirect ?? You cannot do the both in this page.

Comment: Your question clearly says that you wanted to add an `onclick` attribute to `<a>` using javascript. But the answers are not related to it. Can someone help me understand this please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not `prop`, it is `attr`, because `onclick` is a attribute, not a property. But I would add a `click` event listener with jQuery to the element and execute your action there in a callback:

```
$('.edit-user a').click(function(e) {
    // this stops the 'href' of the anchor from being executed
    // if you want the user to follow the 'href' after click, remove the line
    e.preventDefault();

    Popup("address_edit", "Edit", "900", "500");
});
```

Comment: thanks, it works, i didnt knew I had to dynamically bind this, very helpful community

Answer (score 1):

Add click event like this :

```
$('.edit-user a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    Popup("address_edit","Edit","900","500");

    // I don't know if you need to redirect after popup open
    window.location.href = "example.com/nokidding";
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It's attr not prop. You can handle it like this:

```
$('.edit-user a').on('click', function() {
    Popup("address_edit", "Edit", "900", "500");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use dynamic biding for this because you are creating element dynamically. Use below

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit-user a', function() {
Popup("address_edit", "Edit", "900", "500");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm my demo :

```js
$('.edit-user a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    console.log(href);
    //Popup(href, "Edit", "900", "500"); //open popup
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="edit-user">
     <a href="example.com/nokidding">No kidding</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: I feel very happy about that

Answer (score 0):

**This should work :)**

```js
$(document).ready(function(e){
$(".link").attr('onclick','Popup("address_edit","Edit","900","500");');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="link" href="example.com/nokidding">No kidding</a>
```